# Take a file, read it, parse the name and amount, and isolate the top ten donors

Tags: vb.net, function, parsing

So I have a school assignment where my professor has given us a text document with the names of 4,000,000 donors and 4,000,000 different donation amounts. The format of the document is simply just "Name,82" (no space between number and name). With this list of 4,000,000 donors I'm supposed to create a VB program that displays the top 10 donors using a PARSE.

I'm really stumped and have no idea where to begin with the PARSE. I'm not asking you to just do my homework I just need help on where to look or what to start with. This is what I have so far. Let me know if I'm headed in the right direction or completely wrong.

[image]

```
    Public Class CsvTopDonorsParser : Inherits TopDonorsParser
ReadOnly donorNames(NumTopDonorsWanted) As String
ReadOnly donationAmounts(NumTopDonorsWanted) As Decimal



Protected Overrides Sub ParseLineFromText(ByVal line As String)



End Sub

Protected Overrides Function GetTopDonorsCore() As String
    ?   
    Return ""
End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've really tried anything before asking your question... your code is pretty empty!

What do you think the strategy should look like? Can you produce an outline of what you'd like to do in pseudocode to at least go through the thought process of solving the problem?

Comment: "I'm really stumped and have no idea where to begin with the PARSE. I'm not asking you to just do my homework I just need help on where to look or what to start with."

Comment: I'd start by opening the file you're trying to parse.

Comment: Parse probably refers to splitting the Name from the amount - look at `String.Split` for that.  The rest - finding the top ten - there are many ways to go about it.  I would look to simply retaining 10 and something like adding the one just read and remove the lowest one.  Maybe a `SortedList` (its an actual .NET thing not a concept) and wouldnt even have to write a comparer.  Depends on the speed.

Comment: ...and with 4,000,000 lines, I recommend **not** using anything that will attempt to read all the lines at once or store all of them in memory at the same time.  Look for methods to read a file only one line at a time.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great place for me to start. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to read and store that many entries cannot be done in side software.  I think that is the point the professor is trying to drive home.  Well we have enough room for 10 I'm sure. What if you read one checked it against your list of top entries and if you find the one you have is better than one the 10 ten replace it with the one you have.

```
Dim FileDlg As FileDialog
Dim FlgRst As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
Dim File As System.IO.StreamReader
FileDlg = New OpenFileDialog
FlgRst = FileDlg.ShowDialog()
If (FlgRst = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    File = New IO.StreamReader(FileDlg.FileName)
    Dim sLine As String
    sLine = File.ReadLine()
    Dim TestArray() As String = sLine.Split(New Char() {","c})
End If
```

You can look at the contents of the TestArray and see if you can get it from there.  If not give a yell

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I'm trying to do here. That is where I am stumped. How do I separate out the number from the document and checked it against the next line?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really stumped and have no idea where to begin with the PARSE.

**Hint**: to parse lines, you can parse each line you read (fileRecord) from your file using Split method.

```
Dim words As String() = fileRecord.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

now you have 2 words the first is the donor name and the second is the amount (but in string format). You now need to manage how to store and sort this data to get your top ten records. There are different ways to do this.

As for the GUI, I'd expect that you provide a file dialog for the user to select the file from and press a button to begin the process. I am not sure what the other buttons you have are for.

Comment: The other buttons are for a different part of the project. Once I have the top 10 donors then I have buttons for copying them to my clip board and saving as a .txt

Comment: you could just create a file and write the content to a text file using your listbox as the source